# Python Tkinter не видит экземпляр "TimePL" виджета Label

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, tkinter, label

Мой код не видит виджет типа Label

```
line 67, in getPos
    TimePL.configure(text=pos)
NameError: name 'TimePL' is not defined
```

Код:

```
import random
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from pygame import mixer
from threading import Thread
import PyQt5
mixer.init()
background_name = "background.gif"
class MusicPlayer:
    def __init__(self, window ):
        r = random.randint(0,100)
        if(r == 33):
            window_name = "Chocolate StarFish and HotDog flavored Water Player"
        elif(r == 66):
            window_name = "Chocolate StarFish player"
        else:
            window_name = "StarFish Player"
        window.geometry('1000x665'); window.title(window_name); window.resizable(0,0)
        img = PhotoImage(file=background_name)
        label = Label(root, image=img)
        label.image_ref = img
        label.pack()
        Load = Button(window, text = 'Load',  width = 10, font = ('Times', 10), command = self.load)
        Play = Button(window, text = 'Play',  width = 10,font = ('Times', 10), command = self.play)
        Pause = Button(window,text = 'Pause',  width = 10, font = ('Times', 10), command = self.pause)
        Stop = Button(window ,text = 'Stop',  width = 10, font = ('Times', 10), command = self.stop)
        Volm = Button(window, text = "Volume -", width = 10, font = ("Times", 10), command = self.Volm)
        Volp = Button(window, text = "Volume +", width = 10, font = ("Times", 10), command = self.Volp)
        TimePL = Label(text="", font=("Times",10))
        TimeAll = Label(text="TimeAL", font=("Times", 10))
        AudioName = Label(text="AudioName", font =("Times", 10))
        mixer.music.set_volume(1)
        Load.place(x=0,y=20);Play.place(x=110,y=20);Pause.place(x=220,y=20);Stop.place(x=110,y=60); Volm.place(x=0, y=60); Volp.place(x=220,y=60); TimePL.place(x=480, y=500)
        self.music_file = False
        self.playing_state = False
    def load(self):
        self.music_file = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    def play(self):
        if self.music_file:
            mixer.init()
            mixer.music.load(self.music_file)
            mixer.music.play()
        TimePL.get()
    def pause(self):
        if not self.playing_state:
            mixer.music.pause()
            self.playing_state=True
        else:
            mixer.music.unpause()
            self.playing_state = False
    def stop(self):
        mixer.music.stop()
        self.music_file = False
    def Volp(self):
        volume = mixer.music.get_volume()
        volume = volume * 100 + 5
        if(volume <= 100):
            mixer.music.set_volume(volume/100)
    def Volm(self):
        volume = mixer.music.get_volume()
        volume = volume * 100 - 5
        if(volume >= 0):
            mixer.music.set_volume(volume/100)
    def getPos(self):
        pos = mixer.music.get_pos()/1000
        print("Time played: "+str(pos))
        TimePL.configure(text=pos)
    def repeated(self):
        self.getPos(self)
root = Tk()
app= MusicPlayer(root)
def repeated():
    MusicPlayer.repeated(MusicPlayer)
    root.after(1000, repeated)
root.after(0, repeated())
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не проверял логику вашего приложения, а просто устранил некоторые ошибки, которые мне попались.

Вы должны сделать объект `TimePL` атрибутом класса **`self.TimePL`**, тогда вы получите доступ к нему в любом методе класса.

```
import random
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from pygame import mixer

# ??? from threading import Thread
# ??? import PyQt5

mixer.init()
background_name = "gif.gif"                          # установите свое изображение

class MusicPlayer:
    def __init__(self, window):
        super().__init__()
    
        r = random.randint(0, 100)
        if(r == 33):
            window_name = "Chocolate StarFish and HotDog flavored Water Player"
        elif(r == 66):
            window_name = "Chocolate StarFish player"
        else:
            window_name = "StarFish Player"
            
        window.geometry('1000x665'); 
        window.title(window_name); window.resizable(0,0)
        img = PhotoImage(file=background_name)
        label = Label(root, image=img)
        label.image_ref = img
        label.pack()
        Load = Button(window, text = 'Load',  width = 10, font = ('Times', 10), command = self.load)
        Play = Button(window, text = 'Play',  width = 10,font = ('Times', 10), command = self.play)
        Pause = Button(window,text = 'Pause',  width = 10, font = ('Times', 10), command = self.pause)
        Stop = Button(window ,text = 'Stop',  width = 10, font = ('Times', 10), command = self.stop)
        Volm = Button(window, text = "Volume -", width = 10, font = ("Times", 10), command = self.Volm)
        Volp = Button(window, text = "Volume +", width = 10, font = ("Times", 10), command = self.Volp)

#        TimePL = Label(text="", font=("Times",10))
# +++   vvvv
        self.TimePL = Label(text="", font=("Times",10))                   # +++ self

        TimeAll = Label(text="TimeAL", font=("Times", 10))
        AudioName = Label(text="AudioName", font =("Times", 10))
        mixer.music.set_volume(1)
        Load.place(x=0,y=20);
        Play.place(x=110,y=20);
        Pause.place(x=220,y=20);
        Stop.place(x=110,y=60); 
        Volm.place(x=0, y=60); 
        Volp.place(x=220,y=60); 
        self.TimePL.place(x=480, y=500)                                   # +++ self
        self.music_file = False
        self.playing_state = False
        
    def load(self):
        self.music_file = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        
    def play(self):
        if self.music_file:
            mixer.init()
            mixer.music.load(self.music_file)
            mixer.music.play()
# ???        self.TimePL.get()
        
    def pause(self):
        if not self.playing_state:
            mixer.music.pause()
            self.playing_state=True
        else:
            mixer.music.unpause()
            self.playing_state = False
            
    def stop(self):
        mixer.music.stop()
        self.music_file = False
        
    def Volp(self):
        volume = mixer.music.get_volume()
        volume = volume * 100 + 5
        if(volume <= 100):
            mixer.music.set_volume(volume/100)
            
    def Volm(self):
        volume = mixer.music.get_volume()
        volume = volume * 100 - 5
        if(volume >= 0):
            mixer.music.set_volume(volume/100)
            
    def getPos(self):
        pos = mixer.music.get_pos()/1000
        print("Time played: "+ str(pos))

        self.TimePL.configure(text=pos)                               # +++ self
        
    def repeated(self):
#        self.getPos(self)
        self.getPos()                                                 # +++
        
        
root = Tk()
app= MusicPlayer(root)

def repeated():
# ???    MusicPlayer.repeated(MusicPlayer)
    app.repeated()                                                    # +++ 

    root.after(1000, repeated)
    
root.after(0, repeated())

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо, а вот Threading и pyqt5 у меня остались как мусор) забыл убрать

Comment: @3hhr пожалуйста. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour